# mdadm: Is PROGRAM always run by the user root?

Tags: mdadm

I have an mdadm-RAID and want to get notified about events, for example a failing HDD. I can use `MAILADDR` and `PROGRAM` in the mdadm config file to achieve this. I decided to use the latter. So I wrote a simple notification bash-script and set the `PROGRAM`-option to the script's path.

To avoid that each and every user can use this script to send notifications only the root-user has the execute-right on that script. So when mdadm wants to send a notification it must run the script as root.

However I cannot find any option to set the user. Is it always root by default?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it will run as root, as long as `mdadm --monitor` is being run as root (which is the normal case).

I found the MAILADDR option in `mdadm.conf` more flexible in this respect. On my server any email is sent to a specially created user, for which an entry in `.procmailrc` does execute a program with that user as owner. That program is located in a directory not accessible by any other (normal) users (it sends a notification from my server to my desktop on my work machine, in addition to forwarding the email).